# Prove that a positive definite matrix has positive entries on the diagonal

Tags: real-analysis, matrix-calculus

I understand that the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix must be positive, but if the matrix isn't diagonalizable, does this still hold?
Also, it doesn't seem like the reverse would be true but I can't think of a counterexample, so that would also be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Can a matrix both have eigenvalues and not be diagonalizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear transformation $P: V \to V$ is positive definite if and only if $\langle P(v),v \rangle >0$ for each non-zero vector $v,$ where $\langle, \rangle$ is a positive definite inner product on $V$. In particular if $\{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n} \}$ is an orthonormal basis with respect to $\langle, \rangle$, then we have $\langle P(v_{i}), v_{i} \rangle >0$ for each $i.$ Hence $v_{i}$ appears with real positive coefficient when $P(v_{i})$ is expressed as a linear combination of $\{v_{1},v_{2}, \ldots, v_{n} \}.$ This means precisely that the matrix for $P$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $\{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n} \}$ has positive entries on the diagonal. In particular, this applies when $\langle, \rangle$ is the standard inner product, and $\{v_{1},\ldots,v_{n} \}$ is the standard basis.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint (necessity):**
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a&\color{#A0A0A0}{b}&\color{#A0A0A0}{c}&\color{#A0A0A0}{d}\\
\color{#A0A0A0}{e}&f&\color{#A0A0A0}{g}&\color{#A0A0A0}{h}\\
\color{#A0A0A0}{j}&\color{#A0A0A0}{k}&m&\color{#A0A0A0}{n}\\
\color{#A0A0A0}{p}&\color{#A0A0A0}{q}&\color{#A0A0A0}{r}&s
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}=m
$$
**Counterexample (insufficiency):**
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2\\
-2&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1
\end{bmatrix}=-2
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I chose the other answer because they wrote out the proof explicitly but I really appreciate your answer as well!

Comment: I am glad [you found my answer useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).